# Displaying form elements inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am following the tutorial from http://www.sitepoint.com/building-list-jquery-local-storage/
 to build a todo list and I want to display for elements in the same line. At the moment form elements are stacked over each other and displayed vertically but I want them to be displayed vertically. I ultimately want to achieve a result that looks like this:

[image]

Here is the CSS [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/76w02s1z/)

```
.task-list{
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    min-height: 240px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;

}

.task-list input, .task-list textarea{
    width: 240px;
    margin: 1px 5px;


}

.task-list input{
    height: 30px;

}

.todo-task{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.task-list input[type="button"]{
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;

}

.todo-task > .task-header{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.todo-task > .task-date{
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
}

.todo-task > .task-description{
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

Here is the html code

```
<div class="task-list">
  <h3>Add a task</h3>
  <form id="todo-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Task Name" />
    <textarea placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Due (dd/mm/yyyy)" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Task" onclick="todo.add();" />
  </form>

  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Clear Data" onclick="todo.clear();" />
  <div id="delete-div">
    Drag Here to Delete
  </div>
</div>

<div class="task-list task-container" id="pending">
  <h3>Pending</h3>
  <!--<div class="todo-task">
  <div class="task-header">Sample Header</div>
  <div class="task-date">25/06/1992</div>
  <div class="task-description">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</div>
  </div>-->
</div>
```

Comment: What about your dependencies? It's TW Boostrap? Could you setup a JSFiddle?

Comment: You set the width of `.task-list` to 250px, and the width of each input to 240px. How can they fit side by side?

Comment: I've copied his code into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/76w02s1z/

Comment: The code is copied from http://www.sitepoint.com/building-list-jquery-local-storage/ which used Bootstrap 2.2.2

Comment: Barmar ,Thanks for setting up the jsfiddle

Comment: like Barmar said, get rid of `width: 250px;` in your `.task-list` class. Little hint: Don't copy / paste tutorial code. if you use tutorials to learn stuff you should go through it line by line and understand it.

Comment: Getting rid of width: 250px helped to get it to be displayed inline

Comment: i still however cant get the elements of the pending list to be displayed inline

Comment: you mean `Sample Header 25/06/1992 Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet` should be displayed inline? `.todo-task div { display: inline-block; }` should do the trick. But you have to edit one more line in your css, which you can find out by yourself.

Comment: todo-task { display: inline-block; } didnt order the elements inline

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change

.task-list {
    width: 250px;

(found at the very top of your css)

to something like

.task-list {
    width: 850px;

this would then give all the elements within the space room to stand side by side...

Comment: Increasing the width in the .task-list doest help is displaying elements in 'pending' bod side by side